# Is the 1,4-adduct of carbonyl compounds ever a major product over the 1,2-adduct?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, resonance

If, say, propenal undergoes nucleophilic addition of hydrazine, will the 1,2- adduct or the 1,4-adduct be preferred? Why?

There is an obvious reasonace structure with an electrophilic beta carbon so under proper conditions will the 1,4-adduct dominate?

Comment: Organocuprates have much higher tendency to add in a 1,4- fashion. Selectivity can be tuned as a function of the reagent (usually).

Comment: Google for 'Michael addition' and you'll find that in fact plenty of nucleophiles add 1,4-.

Comment: @orthocresol I found out about the Michael addition after posting this question but I can't find anything about hydrazine adding 1,4 to an enone. My textbook mentions a similar addition reaction producing a 1,2-adduct. So I'm confused when I should rule out the 1,4- adduct.

Comment: That's because hydrazine is special: it has two NH2 groups, so one can condense with the carbonyl group to form an imine, and the other one can add to the double bond.

Comment: @orthocresol So does that mean the product wouldn't be a hydrazone as one might expect?